# Dealing microphotography

Tags: macro, microscopy

How would you suggest a micro photograph using a 18-55 mm,14 mp lens?
I have tried many different articles on this but did not succeed.

Comment: You might want to add more specifics. It would help if you posted your pictures too.

Comment: Hi kayD, it's really not very clear what you're asking. Can you point us to a sample or two that will help?

Comment: actually i want  to shoot a mosquito or a fly or a bee..
how can i have a decent shot with these lens specifications.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to take a *Macro* photo. *Macro* is generally defined as a type of photography where the size of the subject on the film negative or sensor is the same size as the subject itself.

To take a large picture of a small subject requires a high *reproduction ratio*. Most 18-55mm lenses don't allow you to focus close enough to get anywhere near a 1:1 reproduction ratio. You can either purchase a *Macro* lens, or you can use *extension tubes* to reduce the *Minimum Focus Distance (MFD)* of your 18-55mm lens. Be aware that using extension tubes to reduce the MFD carries a light loss (effectively they *stretch* the light in the image circle, thus the part that falls on your sensor is less) and also eliminates the ability to focus on far objects.

Some extension tubes will allow you to use automatic exposure and focus, but many do not. How you can set the aperture with a set of manual extension tubes vary by camera manufacturer. For Canon lenses, you can attach the lens directly to the camera set manual mode, set the aperture you want, and remove the lens while holding the *Depth of Field Preview* button down. Then attach the extension tube to the camera and the lens to the extension tube. You will then need to focus manually as well. One way to do that is with Live View magnified on your subject.